# PostSharp Logging Add >>> and <<< to Method Entry/Exit Log Entries

Tags: c#, nlog, postsharp

Can someone please tell me if it's possible to add >>> and <<< to the log entries made by PostSharp Logging at method entry and exit?  If it's possible, can someone please help get me started?

Google has not been a friend and PostSharp's documentation hasn't been helpful, either.  I see where I can create a custom formatter or backend, but I don't see in those examples how to customize the log entry for method entry versus method exit.

Actual PostSharp Log Output w/ NLog

```
2021-10-01 16:29:16.5539|DEBUG|jaslibdss.libddss|    libddss.get_Database()|Starting.
2021-10-01 16:29:16.5539|DEBUG|jaslibdss.libddss|    libddss.get_Database()|Succeeded: returnValue = "master", executionTime = 0.11 ms.
```

Desired PostSharp Log Output w/ NLog

```
2021-10-01 16:29:16.5539|DEBUG|jaslibdss.libddss|   >>> libddss.get_Database()|Starting.
2021-10-01 16:29:16.5539|DEBUG|jaslibdss.libddss|   <<< libddss.get_Database()|Succeeded: returnValue = "master", executionTime = 0.11 ms.
```

I'm using the following:

```
NLog nuget 4.7.11
PostSharp nuget 6.9.9
PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics nuget 6.9.9
PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.NLog nuget 6.9.9
```

I'm using NLog configuration pulled straight from their example:

```
      // Configure NLog.
      var nlogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();

      var fileTarget = new FileTarget("file")
      {
        FileName = "nlog.log",
        KeepFileOpen = true,
        ConcurrentWrites = false
      };

      nlogConfig.AddTarget(fileTarget);
      nlogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget));

      var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget("console");
      nlogConfig.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
      nlogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget));



      // Configure PostSharp Logging to use NLog.
      LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new NLogLoggingBackend(new LogFactory(nlogConfig));

      LogManager.EnableLogging();
```

I don't have any other code to show because I don't know where to begin to code this.

*** Edit ***

```
    internal class MyBackend : NLogLoggingBackend
    {
        public override MyLogBuilder CreateRecordBuilder()
        {
            return new MyLogBuilder(this);
        }
    }

    internal class MyLogBuilder : NLogLogRecordBuilder
    {
        public MyLogBuilder(NLogLoggingBackend backend) : base(backend)
        {
           
        }

        protected override void Write()
        {

        }
    }
```

Tried this so far but "protected override void Write()" is telling me there is no suitable Write method to override.  I do see a WriteCustomString method, however.  Is that what you meant?

*** Edit #2 ***

```
    internal class MyBackend : NLogLoggingBackend
    {
        public MyBackend(LoggingConfiguration config) : base(new LogFactory(config))
        {

        }

        public override MyLogRecordBuilder CreateRecordBuilder()
        {
            return new MyLogRecordBuilder(this);
        }
    }

    internal class MyLogRecordBuilder : NLogLogRecordBuilder
    {
        public MyLogRecordBuilder(NLogLoggingBackend backend) : base(backend)
        {

        }

        public void Write()
        {
            if (this.RecordKind == LogRecordKind.MethodEntry)
            {
                base.Write(new PostSharp.Patterns.Formatters.UnsafeString(">>> Hello, world!"));
            }
            
            if (this.RecordKind == LogRecordKind.MethodSuccess)
            {
                base.Write(new PostSharp.Patterns.Formatters.UnsafeString("<<< Hello, world!"));
            }
        }
    }
```

then

```
            // Configure NLog.
            var nlogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();

            var fileTarget = new FileTarget("file")
            {
                FileName = "nlog.log",
                KeepFileOpen = true,
                ConcurrentWrites = false,
            };

            nlogConfig.AddTarget(fileTarget);
            nlogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget));

            var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget("console");
            nlogConfig.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
            nlogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget));

            LogManager.EnableLogging();


            // Configure PostSharp Logging to use NLog.
            NLogLoggingBackend b = new MyBackend(nlogConfig);
            //b.Options.IndentSpaces = 0;
            LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = b;
```

With this, however, I'm getting a stack overflow error.  :/

*** Edit 3 ***

```
    public class MyBackend : NLogLoggingBackend
    {
        public MyBackend(LoggingConfiguration config) : base(new LogFactory(config))
        {
            Options.IndentSpaces = 4;
            Options.Delimiter = " - ";
            Options.IncludeType = false;
        }

        public override MyLogRecordBuilder CreateRecordBuilder()
        {
            return new MyLogRecordBuilder(this);
        }
    }

    [Log(AttributeExclude = true)]
    public class MyLogRecordBuilder : NLogLogRecordBuilder
    {
        public MyLogRecordBuilder(NLogLoggingBackend backend) : base(backend)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(@"DEBUG---" + backend.Options.Delimiter);
            System.Console.WriteLine(@"DEBUG---" + backend.Options.IndentSpaces);
        }

        protected override void Write(UnsafeString message)
        {
            if (this.RecordKind == LogRecordKind.MethodEntry)
            {
                base.Write(new PostSharp.Patterns.Formatters.UnsafeString(">>> Hello, world!"));
            }

            if (this.RecordKind == LogRecordKind.MethodSuccess)
            {
                base.Write(new PostSharp.Patterns.Formatters.UnsafeString("<<< Hello, world!"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit #3 is my current code that works.  I'm getting log output now with <<< and >>> in the log entry text.  However, I can't get any of the backend.Options to apply.  For example, I'm stuck with the default delimiter of | and I'm not getting any indentation at all.

Note: In my two DEBUG WriteLine's above I do see the expected Option values of " - " and 4 spaces for indenting.

Question:  When I overwrite the Write method do I need to add anything special to make use of these Options or should these be applying and I'm doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a custom logging back-end derived from `NLogLoggingBackend`.

- Create a class derived from `NLogLoggingBackend`.
- Create a class derived from `NLogLogRecordBuilder`.
- Override `NLogLoggingBackend.CreateRecordBuilder` so that it returns a new instance of your `NLogLogRecordBuilder`.
- Override `NLogLogRecordBuilder.Write`. You can call the base `NLogLogRecordBuilder.Write` method with your own string.

  - Alternatively, you can also call directly NLog.Logger, which you can get from the expression `((NLogLoggingTypeSource) this.TypeSource).Logger`.
  - To determine the kind of message (entry, success, failure), use `LogRecordBuilder.RecordKind`
- Alternatively you can override `AppendProlog` and insert your `>>>` or `<<<` before you call `base.AppendProlog` (by appending it to `this.StringBuilder`), but then your characters will be inserted even before the indentation.

Comment: Updated question with what I've tried so far based on your input.  However, I'm not seeing a Write method to override.  Did you mean WriteCustomString?

Comment: Did NOT mean to edit your answer!  Sorry!  :/

Comment: The method you need to override in the record builder is `protected override void Write( UnsafeString message )`.

Comment: Thank you.  This helped.  Figured it out.  Marking this as the accepted answer.  Thanks again.  Appreciate it.

Comment: When I override the Write method in the LogRecordBuilder should the Backend.Options I set be applied automatically or do I need to do something to get them to apply?  I've updated the question (Edit #3) with current code that is generating output with >>> and <<<.  Now I just need to get the delimiter and indentation to work.

Comment: If you want to insert text within the string (and not before or after), you should customize `AppendProlog`. I've copied the original implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/gfraiteur/f403e9847858eb251016da5c095166b2). I guess you will want to add your characters after the call to `AppendIndentString`. You can also override `AppendIndentString` if that's easier.